# Using argumentum ad verecundiam as a verb

Tags: grammar, latin, logic

When referring to logical fallacies in code mixed sentences, I typically see them used as nouns:

> "Of course I'm cool, my mom says I'm cool!"
>   "That appears to be an argumentum ad verecundiam."

If we use an English equivalent we can substitute argument with appeal and have:

> "Of course I'm cool, my mom says I'm cool!"
>   "You may be appealing to authority."

Can argumentum ad verecundiam, or an accepted modification of it, be used as a verb, in a way that doesn't seem forced?

The intent behind this is to debase a rebuttal by making it pretentious and introducing elements of argumentum verbosium. Additionally adding a bit of ad hominem by moving from:

> "The argument might be fallacious"

to:

> "Your action might be fallacious"

Thus focusing more on the person than their argument.

I suspect that this can't be done in a smooth manner due to "argumentum ad verecundiam" being treated as a single word. As such changing it to another part of speech does strange things to its meaning or takes it from uncommon usage to non existent usage:

"You may be argumentuming ex verecundiam" gives something of the impression that I would like, but is in the non existent usage world. Preventing it from giving pretentious but, to some, understandable meaning. And the use of the hybrid word makes it sound forced to me.

Comment: Anything can be used as a verb. But do you think your readers/hearers will understand you?

Comment: All you will elicit is laughter if you try that. If all  you want is to appear supercilious, go right ahead.

Comment: I have always wondered how 'ad verecundiam' relates to this particular phenomenon of reasoning.  I found a long exposition in P.L.E [https://philosophy.lander.edu/logic/authority.html], which leaves me little the wiser.  I do not know why you would want a verb.  I thought the point of remarks like the one you quote is lent ironic humour by the (dare I say?) pretentiously long-winded Latin.

Comment: I'm confused...can you give an example of what you want to do, an actual sentence? 'Appeal' is a verb in English here, but 'argumentum' is a noun in Latin and used as a noun in English. Do you want to use 'argumentum' as a verb in English?

Comment: The post needs to be re-drafted. It's logically incorrect as @Mitch explained above.

Comment: @Mitch Thank you for your questions. I've clarified the question somewhat. To address your note, it wouldn't have to be using argumentum as a verb. In the same way that we replace argument with appeal in English, could the same be done in a Latin hybrid? Perhaps "appealing ad verecundiam"?

Comment: @Amos It's still unclear what you are looking for. You're not giving a sentence with a blank and possible fillers. You can't say "You may be verecundiaming" or any variation (which is the only thing I can imagine you're asking about. Just come right out and give a sentence.

Comment: @Mitch I’m thinking y’all meant to have written that were *those verecundiae being argumentummed in extremis*, that the correct passive imperfect subjunctive in the second person plural would then have necessarily had to have been *arguereminī*, you meanie!

Comment: @Amos Thanks for the edit. It makes it clear exactly what you're looking for (whereas before it could easily have been other things). That said, I think Jeremy answered the clarified question well.

Comment: But now I am wondering what the motivation is (beyond curiosity or creativity). You can say either 'Don't appeal to force' or 'Don't use argumentum ad baculum'; why would you care for another way to say it by modifying the syntax of either? The bigger point is that while in the late Middle/early Modern English there was a huge influx of Latinisms, nowadays it sounds very unnatural or hyper-academic to force a Latin inflected word into an English situation. 'Verecundify'? 'Verecundize'? Maybe it's just that one vocab item but all variations sound awful.

Comment: I think 'Don't use argumentum ad baculum' is what I'm looking for. It moves the statement from the argument to the person making it, somewhat, more irritating. As for why I'm looking for an answer to this, mostly so that when my kids employ such arguments I can respond in an annoying manner "What is wrong with you? What does that even mean?" is one of my favorite things to hear my children say to me.

Answer (score 3):

Just no. It cannot.  If for, whatever reason that seems good to you, you wish to use a technical term from Latin rhetoric, then by all means do so, but only after explaining what you mean in plain English.

There is a very small set of foreign language words or expressions that may be used in English without explanation or translation but even then you risk being regarded as pretentious. If you seek to introduce into written English terms that even highly educated native speakers would not understand, then you will fail to communicate. You might also arouse negative emotions that will actively obstruct any communication that you wish to make.

Comment: This is along the lines of what is intended. Just can it be stated in a way that doesn't sound forced. It need only be intelligible to people who happen to know what argumentum ad verecundiam means.